# how does mdm (mobile device management ) work in byod environment to control the camera?

Tags: mobile, documents

what i want to know is how  mdm (mobile device management ) works in byod environment to control the camera from clicking pictures of a printed document?is there a way other than to shut off the camera or by not allowing mobile phones with camera?

Comment: BYOD is not a factor. MDM clients work by turning off the hardware.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already surmised, the only thing you can do is to prevent the camera from working at all.

Unfortunately, tiny camera's are prevalent everywhere now so completely preventing this issue is pretty well impossible without taking very extreme actions.

Answer (score 2):

MDM offers you a false sense of security. In a BYOD environment, you are not the admin of the device, and thus cannot be sure your technical controls will work.

In practical situations, employees trying to exfiltrate data always beat technical controls trying to prevent them from doing so, because they are smarter and more capable than the technical controls. (If this is not the case, you're probably hiring the wrong employees.) This kind of behavior is a human problem, and is best solved with a human solution, like employee counseling and awareness initiatives, articulation of consequences, or even just trying to make your disgruntled employees happier.

Disabling someone's camera will not solve the human problem, and will probably make it worse.